# Drive API - Create File

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google is depreciating the DocsList API and I'm trying to find a workaround for DocsList.createFile (pdf), but can't seem to locate the method on how to do this? I basically just want a pdf copy of the file stored on my Drive when the script is ran.

Any help would be great!

```
DocsList.createFile(pdf);
MailApp.sendEmail({
to:"email address here",
subject: "Weekly File" + "_" + "Sent on " + CopyDate,
body:"(This is an automated email.).....Attached is a copy of the weekly file sent on" + "      "+CopyDate,
attachments: [pdf]
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ughh no sooner after I post did I find the answer. If anyone else needs to know its

```
DriveApp.createfile(pdf)
```

Sorry for wasting anyones time!